# Hough Line: Detect ticks on the image

Tags: opencv

I am trying the detect ticks on the following image using hough line transformation:
[image]

I am using the following simple open CV code:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imwrite('original.jpg',img)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges,1,np.pi/180,200)
for rho,theta in lines[0]:
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    x0 = a*rho
    y0 = b*rho
    x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
    x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
    y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))

    cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),2)
```

I am getting the following output:
[image]

I wanted to detect the ticks, but instead it detected the lines. How can I solve it? Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please output "edges" image too? And what is that "200" parameter in houghLines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "ticks", I guess the green and red lines?!?

Using `C++ API` and `HoughLinesP`:

function call:

```
cv::HoughLinesP(edges, lines, 1, CV_PI/720.0, 30, 10 /* min-length */, 1 /* max gap */);
```

canny:

```
cv::Mat edges;
cv::Canny(gray, edges, 50, 150, 3);
```

I get this result for canny:

edges look like this

[image]

that's why the result looks like:

[image]

but using edges from thresholds:

```
edges = gray > 50;
```

edge image:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: you can probably increase result quality if you know that those lines are always either red or green, so thresholding might give even much better results.

Comment: Hi, yes i meant the green and red shapes.

Comment: Is the "threshold" version a help/solution or what are you missing?

Comment: Hi Micka, this is the one what I am expecting. Is it possible to get the lines which intersects each other 90 degree?

Comment: Hi Micka, can you explain me what does 'edges = gray > 50;' mean? I meant what does it do.

Comment: Gray > 50 results in the Mat where each pixel that has a value of bigger than 50 in the source Mat "Gray" is set to 255 in the destination Mat. So its just a simple thresholding. If you use R and G channel instead grayscale image it might become even better.

Comment: Thank you Micka. Which threshold value produced the result image? I used cv2.Canny(gray,100,150,apertureSize = 3) (till 100) but i did not get like yours.

Comment: dont use the canny, remove canny and use `edges = gray > 50` instead